# How to include a temp image file into html in SwiftUI on iOS

Tags: html, swiftui, webview

I have an app that has image data saved in CoreData and I need to include those images on internally generated web pages generated from the CoreData info. The following app demonstrates my problem exclusive of the core data for simplicity. I can't figure out how to reference the local temp file with the image. If there is a way to do this without a temp file directly from the CoreData data, that would be even better.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var html = "<html><body>Image below<br><img src='+++' width='400'></body></html>"
    let img = Image("pic") // any pic as an asset for demo purposes
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            img.resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            Button("Click")
            {
                do
                {
                    let image = UIImage(named: "pic")
                    
                    let tmp = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
                    let file = tmp.appendingPathComponent("myfile").appendingPathExtension("png")
                    if let data = image?.pngData()
                    {
                        try data.write(to: file)
                    }
                    html = html.replacingOccurrences(of: "+++", with: file.absoluteString)
                    print(html)
                }
                catch
                {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            WebView(text: html)
            TextField("html", text: $html)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the answer to the actual question about using a temp file but just ended up embedding the image in the url as base64 data:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var html = "<html><body>Image below<br><img src='+++' width='400'/></body></html>"
    let img = Image("pic")
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            img.resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            Button("Click")
            {
                if let image = UIImage(named: "pic")
                {
                    if let data = image.pngData()
                    {
                        let ttxt = "data:image/png;base64," + data.base64EncodedString()
                        html = html.replacingOccurrences(of: "+++", with: ttxt)
                    }
                }
            }
            WebView(text: html)
            TextField("html", text: $html)
        }
    }
}
```